# How can I parse a file path and get its parent's parent's directory?

Tags: ant

Using Ant - in a buildfile - how can I parse a file path and get its parent's parent's directory?

```
<target name="test">
 <property name="jar"
  value="D:\F\D\r\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.0.7.R\spring-beans.jar" />
 <echo>${jar}</echo>
</target>
```

I want to get this result:

```
D:\F\D\r\org\springframework\spring-beans
```

Comment: Are you looking parents for only one file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the Ant [`dirname` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/dirname.html), and call it as many times as you need to get parents, parents of parents, etc.:

```
<dirname file="${jar}" property="jar.dir" />
<dirname file="${jar.dir}" property="jar.dir.parent" />
<dirname file="${jar.dir.parent}" property="jar.dir.grandparent" />
```

*(Your example result looks like the parent of the directory holding the jar (i.e. `jar.dir.parent`, but you mention parent's parent.)*

Answer (score 2):

Simply, you can try to use location when setting a property; like this:

```
<property name="jar.parent.dir" location="${jar}/../.."/>
```

You will get:

```
D:\F\D\r\org\springframework\spring-beans
```